# Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program in c# on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8

I would like to show item details with image in continuous pages, with images loaded using `bitmapimage.setsource(new meorystream(byte[]value))`

While navigating a page, an exception occurs such as `"Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program"` in C# on Windows Phone 8 app.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider reducing image quality, if you can

Comment: still i'm having this issue, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have the code you need, I think :

```
 public static MemoryStream CompressImageStream(Stream inputStream)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(inputStream);

            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

            // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream. 
            MemoryStream targetStream = new MemoryStream();

            try
            {
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, targetStream, 100, 100, 0, 80);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            targetStream.Position = 0;

            return targetStream;
        }
```

Check out the " Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, targetStream, 100, 100, 0, 80); "
Which sets the image dimensoin and compress rate.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Another solution that I found useful : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

Try :   image.Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(jpgStream, 192, 256);